# Apply Prize Function To Large DataFrame Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to find out the fastest way to apply a prize to each person in this dataframe based on the status being True (1.0).  I have thousands of rows and the way I was doing it previously was via iterrows.  Needless to say it took to long going through each column, checking if status is true, and then feeding the rank into a function that gave back the prize.  It was something like this.

```
 print dataframeB
 Name         Rank     Status
 James         1         0.0
 Joanne        2         1.0
 Ryan          3         1.0
 Al            4         0.0
 etc...

for index,row in dataframeB.iterrows():
     if row['Status'] == True:
         rank= row['Rank']
    ### Then take the rank of it and feed it into a function that
    ### returned the prize
```

Example of my prize function was something like...

```
def Prize(rank):
  if rank == 1:
   return 100
```

Comment: What is your desired output for this dataframe?

Comment: I would like to get back all the columns that are True with a prize column.

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully your prize function yields next prize so I'll simulate it here:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.Dataframe({'Name': list('abcd'), 'Rank': range(1,5), 'Status': [0,1,1,0]})
prizes = iter([100,50,25,10])
df['Prize'] = df['Status'].apply(lambda x: next(prizes) if x else 0)
df
#Name Rank Status Prize
#a    1    0      0
#b    2    1      100
#c    3    1      50
#d    4    0      0
```

**EDIT**
Based on your comment you need:

```
df['Prize'] = df.apply(lambda x: Prize(x['Rank']) if x['Status'] else 0, axis=1)
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't all that clear with my prize function aspect.  So i want to apply it to every name, but only return the ones in which the status is True.  So I'm not sure if I should filter it out based on Status first and then apply a prize function to save time or just apply it to everything.

Comment: And my prize function would input a rank, and return the prize.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a "big" dataframe and performance is an issue, you want to vectorize this operation with `numpy.where` and `numpy.select`:

```
def prize(ranks):
    return numpy.select(
        [(ranks == 1), ranks == 2, ranks == 3, ranks == 4],
        [100, 50, 25, 10],
        default = 0
    )

df = df.assign(Prize=numpy.where(df['Status'] == 1, prize(df['Rank']), numpy.nan))
```

Comment: Maybe the best is question what is function? ;) and this function vectorized ;)